# How to render Gantt Highchart from data source

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For previous highcharts, I rendered the chart with the following HTTP Get command:

```
$(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://example.com/api", function(data) {
            $('#container').highcharts(data);
        });
    });
```

I am trying to render a Gantt chart with the same format, however only a blank canvas renders.

I tried:

```
$(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://example.com/api", function(data) {
            $('#container').highcharts.ganttChart(data);
        });
    });
```

However I received an error that "ganttChart" did not exist.

How can I render a ganttChart from data?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading *Gantt* dependency either as a standalone library or a module along with *Highcharts*. Then use the `ganttChart` constructor, ie:

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    title: { .. },
    // other configuration options
}, myCallback);
```

See [Getting started with Gantt](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/gantt/getting-started-gantt) for more details and a short [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gvaartjes/87toLqnp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#container').highcharts('ganttChart', data);
```

But you don't need jQuery to create a chart, the below code is enough:

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', data);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ozw8n5v/